# How to process data from Fortran program output effectively

Tags: fortran, output, gfortran

I have an old program called `kirch1.f` found at http://netlib.sandia.gov/conformal/kirch1 and some dependencies `sclibdbl.f` which are found at  http://netlib.org/conformal/sclibdbl.

By running this program I am left with all of the data that has been written to a file (I presume) called `fort.10`

I am new to fortran, in fact I come from a Matlab background, and so the way this is layed out is very foreign to me. I basically have two questions:

1) How do I even open `fort.10` and begin to plot the data contained therein?

2) What is the best way to go about handling this data that I have written to the file? What I like about Matlab is that it is so easy to visualise and manipulate the resulting data type from a script, whereas here it seems like I have to compile and run my program (unavoidable of course) and then open a file and look where I have saved the relevant data i.e. which columns and rows etc. Are there any people out there that can share how they process their Fortran output data?

Comment: Have you tried opening your `fort.10` with a programmer's editor such as Emacs or Vim ?  Do you even know if it is formatted or unformatted (text or binary if you prefer that terminology) ?  FWIW: my Fortran programs write HDF5 files which are readable by many other programs, including Matlab.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - no I have no idea, I'm completely new to fortran. Looking at the source code there is definitely some formatting going on. I would really appreciate if you could show me how you integrate your fortran data file to be able to be read by the likes of Matlab or python..

Comment: Now answer the first question in my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry - yes I did try just now with vim and indeed I can view the data.

Comment: Well now it's simple.  You open the file and read its contents using Matlab -- with which you are already familiar.

Comment: Ah great that was very simple. Is this the conventional way people pass data from fortran?

Comment: It is one of the many possible ways. You coan read whole larhe articles or book chapters about it.

Comment: at a glance the file looks to be human readable with lots of text labels describing the data, etc. I might modify the fortran code to just write the data that you need, so that it will be easier to import.